# Using node as api and static

Tags: node.js, server, domain-name

I'm extremely new to web development. I've bought a domain name (let say 'domain.com' and what I want is to have two links: one 'api.domain.com' with MySql database and Node server for API; and second is: 'domain.com' with some client-side app which will call to 'api.domain.com' for data. Same for native mobile apps which will call 'api.domain.com'.
What NodeJS frameworks will you suggest to best serve this needs. And how are those "domain tricks" called, so I can read about how to organise it.

Comment: I know there are plenty of frameworks for rich webapps, with their template engines and so on. But what if I want to try using LoopBack, which is made specifically for REST APIs. Is it possible to use ONLY LoopBack to response with a singlepage React app for example?

Answer (score -1):

- For bare web framework and middleware abstraction, please see [express](https://expressjs.com)
- For Extensive API development and integration, please see [loopback](https://loopback.io)
- For enterprise features to manage your deployments, please see [strongloop](https://strongloop.com)